renovate matchString function not working
I have this Yaml file
release_units:
  - set: first
    version: 21.71.0
    components: ["FIRST"]

  - set: second 
    version: 3.14.0
    components: ["SECOND"]

  - set: third
    version: 3.10.0
    components: ["TH"]

now i want to onboard renovate to it and search third version and update it with the latest version in artifactory
now my renovate.json looks like this
{
    "$schema": "https://docs.renovatebot.com/renovate-schema.json",
    "extends": [
        "config:base"
    ],
    "registryUrls": [
        "https://test/artifactory/built/abc/component/third/"
    ],
    "regexManagers": [
        {
            "fileMatch": [
                "configuration/release_x86_64\\.yaml$"
            ],
            "matchStrings": [
                "version: (?<currentValue>.+)"
            ],
            "datasourceTemplate": "bitbucket-tags",
            "extractVersionTemplate": "^v?(?<version>.*)$",
            "versioningTemplate": "semver-coerced"
        }
    ]
}

but with this regex mentioned in matchStrings is not working for me somehow.
when I run it with renovate.json it should detect the third version and update it

As per the documentation, there are a few mandatory things for a custom regex manager to work:


You must capture the currentValue of the dependency in a named capture group
You must have either a depName or packageName capture group, or use on of the respective template fields ( depNameTemplate and packageNameTemplate )
You must have either a datasource capture group or a datasourceTemplate config field


You're, at least, missing the depName/packageName.
